# Poles of functions $f(z) = \frac{z-4}{e^z - 1}$

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm trying to understand poles in complex analysis, and Wikipedia states the following example: $$f(z) = \frac{z-4}{e^z - 1}$$ has a simple pole at $z = 2ni\pi$ for $n \in \mathbb{Z}$. I understand this intuitively: $e^z$ behaves like $1+z$ at $2ni\pi$, and it's periodical in the sense that $e^{ix} = e^{i(x+2n\pi)}$. However, I can't find the formal function $g(z)$ such that $g(2ni\pi) \neq 0$ and $f(z) = \frac{g(z)}{z-2ni\pi}$. How can I do this?

Comment: You might not be able to find such  function $g$ in a closed form. However you can find a power series for it around that point.

Comment: A power series for $g$ would be great, even in a small area around $2ni\pi$. How can I find this power series?

Comment: Here's what I have so far: $f(z) = \frac{z-4}{\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \frac{z^n}{n!}}$, so I can see that $f$ has a simple pole at $z=0$, with $g(z) = \frac{z-4}{\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \frac{z^{n-1}}{n!}}$. Can I use this to find $g$ for the other poles?

Comment: $g(z)=\frac{(z-4)(z-2ni\pi)}{e^z-1} $when $z \neq 2ni\pi$ and $g(z)=2ni\pi-4$  when $z=2ni\pi$ does the trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the power series approach as follows(if you know f is holomorphic in the neighborhood of $2ni\pi$, which it is):

Let $g(z)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} b_k (z-2n\pi i)^k$, $f(z)-1=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{(z-2n\pi i)^k}{k!}$

Since,

$$[g(z)][f(z)-1]= (z-2ni\pi_) +(2ni\pi -4)$$
$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} b_k (z-2n\pi i)^k \cdot \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{(z-2n\pi i)^k}{k!} = (z-2ni\pi) +(2ni\pi -4)$$
Now multiply out the LHS and compare the coeffecients to find the $b_k$'s